# Lilypond glissando across piano staves

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I'm trying to typeset the glissando shown below using Lilypond:

[image]

There are examples in the [docs](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-as-lines) but they weren't helpful.

My code:

```
\version "2.24.0"

upper = \relative{
\clef treble
\key c \major
\time 5/4
\override VoiceFollower.style = #'zigzag 
<c'' e fis a>2.\glissando
\change Staff = "lower"
<a,,, a'>4
\change Staff = "upper"
}

lower = \relative{
\clef bass
\key c \major
\time 5/4
<a c e>2. \skip 4 r4
}

\score {\new PianoStaff <<
  \new Staff = "upper" \upper
  \new Staff = "lower" \lower
  >>
\layout {}
\midi { }
}
```

gives me:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To accomplish this, set the `\glissandoMap`, which tells LilyPond which note within each chord to connect via the glissando line.

From the LilyPond documentation (link below):

> A glissando can connect notes in chords. If anything other than a direct one-to-one pairing of the notes in the two chords is required the connections between the notes are defined by setting `\glissandoMap`, where the notes of a chord are assumed to be numbered from zero in the order in which they appear in the input `‘.ly’` file.

In the specific case here, add
`\set glissandoMap = #'((3 . 1))`
after the `VoiceFollower` setting.

For more on `\glissandoMap` see [1.3.3 Expressive marks as lines: Glissando](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-as-lines#glissando) in the LilyPond documentation.

Comment: thanks, is there also a way to include a two-beat rest symbol for the treble staff (like in my screenshot)? Or is it better notation to have a one-beat rest at the end?

Comment: @MedullaOblongata Just as `r2` after changing back to the upper staff, below the closing bracket.